# SwiftUI: Animation problem - fading instead of moving

Tags: animation, swiftui

I’m trying to build a custom sidebar menu that animates out when a button in it is tapped. For debugging purposes the animation is deliberately slow at 2.0 seconds. As you can see the animation does not work properly:

[image]

I suspect there are two parts to this problem:

1. The background of the newly selected button is moving out faster than the menu. I think this is rooted in the default system animation of `Button`.
2. When I replace `Button` with `Text` and use an `.onTapGesture`, there is still the fading animation, so I assume there is something structurally wrong in the way I’m setting `selected` in `FeatureButton`.

Sorry the example code is a bit long, tried to simplify my app architecture as much as possible. The reason for using `MenuState` as an `EnvironmentObject` is to be able to the change its properties from various places throughout the app.

Here’s the code:

```
class MenuState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentFeature: Feature = .featureA
    @Published var menuOffset: CGFloat = 0
}

enum Feature: String, CaseIterable {
    case featureA = "Feature A"
    case featureB = "Feature B"
    case featureC = "Feature C"
}

extension Feature: Identifiable {
    var id: RawValue { rawValue }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var menuState = MenuState()

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            content
            menu
        }
        .environmentObject(menuState)
        .animation(.easeOut(duration: 2.0), value: menuState.menuOffset)
    }

    var menu: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(Feature.allCases) { feature in
                FeatureButton(feature: feature)
            }
        }
        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
        .frame(width: 200)
        .background(.thinMaterial)
        .offset(x: menuState.menuOffset)
    }

    var content: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show Menu") {
                menuState.menuOffset = 0
            }
            Text(menuState.currentFeature.rawValue)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
    }
}

struct FeatureButton: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var menuState: MenuState

    let feature: Feature
    var selected: Bool {
        return menuState.currentFeature == feature
    }

    var body: some View {
        Button(feature.rawValue) {
            menuState.currentFeature = feature
            menuState.menuOffset = -200
        }
        .buttonStyle(FeatureButtonStyle(selected: selected))
    }
}

struct FeatureButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    @EnvironmentObject var menuState: MenuState

    var selected: Bool
    public func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 44)
            .foregroundColor(selected ? .blue : .primary)
            .background(Color.gray.opacity(selected ? 0.4 : 0))
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
    }
}
```

EDIT:
For some reason making the animation explicit solves the issue, see answer below.

Comment: So, it seems you've found a way to solve the problem and can post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be solved by making the animation explicit instead of using the `.animation` modifier:

```
Button(feature.rawValue) {
    menuState.currentFeature = feature
        withAnimation(.easeOut) {
            menuState.menuOffset = -200
        }
    }
.buttonStyle(FeatureButtonStyle(selected: selected))
```

I don't understand why it only works like this though.